# how to write PHP functionality in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Is there any way to write same functionality in jsp to send data to server?
I want to capture image from Flash using Java and send it to the server. Everywhere I search I get the same script to send it to server. Can't jsp do this?

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"] )) {
    $uniqueStamp = date(U);
    $filename = $uniqueStamp.".jpg";
    $fp = fopen( $filename,"wb");
    fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] ); 
    fclose( $fp );

    echo "filename=".$filename."&base=".$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: You want us to write the code for you?

Comment: don't write for me i am capable that much to do that just tell me how can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest ways to upload a file in Java is to leverage [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/). Writing a file is trivial - using core classes from `java.io`.

Comment: off late I came across Apache Commons FileUpload. I downloaded jar file from there. But not geting how to use that..I found there JSp script for uploading. Have you ever tried it?

Comment: Here I found JSP script to upload image to server can i replace it by above PHP code to achieve functionality or need to do some changes in that      http://www.aurigma.com/docs/iuf/saving-uploaded-files-in-other-platforms.htm#JSPSample

Comment: No, you can't replace Java code with PHP. You need to modify Java sample to suit your need, or rewrite your PHP in Java.

Comment: NO NO! I mean to say above PHP code is used for uploading image to server...will the JSP code available on link provided is equivalent to that PHP functionality

Comment: It is not an exact copy, but enough to use. Your code in PHP is very basic: get file contents, write them to a file. The Java sample does almost the same thing, except it seems they are implementing a multi-file upload.

Comment: I am getting confused with that not getting how to use it..

Comment: You need to try and show us what doesn't work.